Was there an Easter egg in the Electrologica X1 QUINIO (GO-MOKU) game?
The CWI software archive on GitHub contains the Algol-60 source code for a gomoku-like game. It is runnable with your favorite Algol-60 compiler and a little elbow grease (in particular, taking the definition of SUM from the Jensen's device article). While it  plays reasonably when it makes the first move (as can be expected of a program of this size and complexity), it immediately prints
  IK GEEF OP
  U HEBT GEWONNEN

if the user makes the first move.
The fact that it plays and does not crash when it moves first proves that transcription errors are unlikely; the code used to select the next move is the same for both modes of play.
My question is for those who remember the Electrologica X1 (or those who can understand the logic of the program). Was it indeed an intended tongue-in-cheek behavior because it is known that the first player in gomoku is expected to win with optimal play?

It turns out that there was a subtle transcription error caused by some of the Algol characters represented by underlining another character, e. g. ↑ is rendered as an underlined ∧, ÷ as an underlined :, and ≤ as an underlined <.
Copy-pasting the source from the .odt document on GitHub ignored the underlines. Restoring the stropping was routine, the bare ∧ and : were easy to fix because they caused syntax errors, but the "less-than" sign which should have been a "less-than-or-equal" remained, causing that peculiar behavior.
Fixing that did the job (in the implementation used, both 'le' or 'notgreat' work, only the first 6 letters of keywords are significant); now the program plays decently both ways.

I told you it was accidental behaviour :-)

Good work, though.

Real languages don't like copy paste programming :)) Well done.

I assumed (when just glancing at the code and paying no attention to the type of the operands) that the ∧ was a proper and symbol.

@dave In other places, indeed, it is; initially I'd replaced the one in 2 ∧ expr with a product sign, thinking of it as a badly OCRed × (surprizingly, the lowercase x and the multipication sign are indistinguishable in the printout)  . With that, the program still plays, but not as well as with the proper power operator.

What are you running this on?  Is there an X-1 simulator with a functioning Algol compiler?

@dave Just the good old BESM-6. Alas, the Algol compiler which uses the authentic character set does not have interactive capabilities that I know of. The other one uses ASCII/ISO, and it appears that ≤ should be given, of all possible ways, as 'notgre',

That choice is notgreat

@LeoB. - this should be the accepted answer.

@dave The system allows to accept one's own answer after 2 days.

Oh, I was unaware there was a waiting period.

I used to read Algol; I have never read Dutch. And the code is not commented to any degree.
But judging by the general layout, I'd say it is accidental. There's a bunch of procedure declarations; the 'main' code starts at the call NLCR (new line carriage return?) about 15 lines from the end of the program, just after procedure SEL, and does some init.
There are distinguished chunks of code at labels MENS and MACH, which I guess to be the man and machine moves.
Presumably we should somehow start at MACH rather than MENS if 'd25' is 0 (some sort of switch register? does XEEN read it?) but I don't see how that happens. There's no reference to MACH in the code; just fall-through from the MENS clause.
(BTW, it's nice to see an Algol 60 program on a proper input device with a decent character set).

My first step was to copy-paste the comment to an online translator to learn than XEEN reads console switches through which all input is done. 33554432 is 2^25, corresponding to switch d25. After a move, the procedure CORR builds a list of prospective moves in X and Y (not all actually worth considering), then SEL selects the best move and returns its index. The program gives up when no proposed moves are "worth considering". This is what happens when the user moves first: the list of proposed moves is reasonable, but they are all rejected. As no moves were considered, SEL returns 0.

Looks like you went deeper than me (my excuse: I was supposed to be at work).  It therefore seems accidental that the program supports 'user goes first' but cannot select a first move for itself.

it's nice to see an Algol 60 program on a proper input device with a decent character seе That aside proved crucial in understanding the issue. While the input device had a decent character set, the output one did not. ↑ is rendered as underlined ∧, ÷ as an underlined :, and ≤ as an underlined <. Copy-pasting from the .odt document on GitHub ignored the underlines; the bare ∧ and : are easy to fix because they cause syntax errors, but the less-than sign is not so much. Fixing it does the job.
